# How to generate AWS signature from JMeter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter

Here is my code in the JSR223 PreProcessor.

```
import javax.crypto.Mac
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
import java.security.InvalidKeyException
import java.security.MessageDigest
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

static byte[] HmacSHA256(String data, byte[] key) throws Exception {
String algorithm="HmacSHA256";
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key, algorithm));
return mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF8"));
```

}

```
static byte[] getSignatureKey(String key, String dateStamp, String regionName, String serviceName) throws Exception {
byte[] kSecret = ("AWS4" + key).getBytes("UTF8");
byte[] kDate = HmacSHA256(dateStamp, kSecret);
byte[] kRegion = HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
byte[] kService = HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
byte[] kSigning = HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);       
return kSigning;
```

}

Example parameter values to the function getSignatureKey are (these I am passing to the Parameters section of the JSR223 PreProcessor as variables)

```
key = eC6hEyRSTXMzsG6+juOObz8LbXb36iEYW7PPN1MJ
dateStamp = 20190123T083434Z
regionName = us-west-2
serviceName = test-mlp-us-west-2-4023179c-7708-4c5e-a831-28259b8a8872.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

This code is not working and not generating the AWS signature.

Here is the sample Signature value I need to get

```
Signature=2a6092ec4ff49dc9j3b92d436635a57f312753kcc9f553ce1718b9b1594c4362
```

1.What is wrong with this code?
2.How can I assign the AWS signature to a variable and use in the JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

If "This code is not working" the first thing you should do is to look into [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) - in case of Groovy script failure it will contain information regarding what exactly failed and why and some hints to fix.

I also think you should generate the signature basing on request details (URL, parameters, headers, etc.)

```
StringToSign =
    Algorithm + \n +
    RequestDateTime + \n +
    CredentialScope + \n +
    HashedCanonicalRequest
```

See [Create a String to Sign for Signature Version 4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-string-to-sign.html)

The whole process with examples is described in the [How to Handle Dynamic AWS SigV4 in JMeter for API Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-dynamic-aws-sigv4-in-jmeter-for-api-testing) and the test plan you can use as the reference is available in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/jinlo02/Jmeter_AWS_Signature).